Can't import C DLL into C# project
I have a C source, and I want execute the functions in a C# project. So, the sources can be similar to the following code:
source.h
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma once

typedef struct {
  bool boolvar;
  float floatvar;
} t_myStruct;

bool FuncA(t_myStruct *myStructPtr);
bool FuncB(t_myStruct *myStructPtr, float myParameter);

source.c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "source.h"

bool FuncA(t_myStruct *myStructPtr) {
  bool something = false;
  // do stuff
  return something;
}

bool FuncB(t_myStruct *myStructPtr, float myParameter) {
  bool something = false;
  // do stuff
  return something;
}

I followed this guide, and i modified my source as follow:
source.h
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma once

#ifdef MYDLL

#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
  #define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#define CALL __cdecl

#endif

#ifdef MYDLL
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
#endif

typedef struct {
  bool boolvar;
  float floatvar;
} t_myStruct;

MYDLL_API bool FuncA(t_myStruct *myStructPtr);
MYDLL_API bool FuncB(t_myStruct *myStructPtr, float myParameter);

#ifdef MYDLL
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

source.c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "source.h"

#ifdef MYDLL
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
#endif

MYDLL_API bool FuncA(t_myStruct *myStructPtr) {
  bool something = false;
  // do stuff
  return something;
}

MYDLL_API bool FuncB(t_myStruct *myStructPtr, float myParameter) {
  bool something = false;
  // do stuff
  return something;
}

#ifdef MYDLL
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // __cplusplus defined.
#endif
#endif

After that, i compiled my sources for product the DLL (i use GCC)
gcc -c -o source.o source.c -lgdi32 -lcomctl32 -DMYDLL_EXPORTS -DMYDLL
gcc -o source.dll source.o -s -shared -Wl,--subsystem,windows

All can be compiled and linked without errors.
In my C# project i add some lines in my sources for reference the functions:
Program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myNamespace
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("source.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        extern static bool FuncA(t_myStruct *myStructPtr);

        [DllImport("source.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        extern static bool FuncB(t_myStruct *myStructPtr);

        /// <summary>
        /// Punto di ingresso principale dell'applicazione.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
}

If I try to add source.dll as reference in my simple C# program, an error occours: error suggests to verify file accessibility and if the assembly is a valid COM component.
What I miss?

You can only use "add reference" with a .NET assembly, and not with a C native dll. But anyway for PInkvoke (which you are using) you don't need to add to the project as a reference. Simply copy the dll to the folder when the exe when it is run.

A side note: you seem to be on Windows. Why don't you use VisualStudio for both building the dll (instead of gcc), and the C# app ? IMHO it is more convenient this way.

Thanks @wohlstad, if I try to compile my code without reference the DLL on the project, compilation returns error CS0246, "the name or the namespace "t_myStruct" can't be found, may be missing using directive or the assembly reference". And the DLL is in the same folder of the sources.
Actually i compile with GCC because it's the same compiler used by the VisualGDB for the Espressif microcontrollers. But the source is written in C, not C++, so I don't know if Visual Studio can compile it, and if I can reference a C project in my .net application.
It's useful for testing the sources for me.

You need to learn how to add a PInvoke marshaling declaration for this struct type (I don't think there's a way around it). This link can get you started. See also this post for struct marshaling with PInvoke. Regarding VisualStudio - it is perfectly capable of compiling C code.

Also in the SO post I shared above (this one), they use ref MYCSSTRUCT mycsstruct instead of a raw pointer like in C (MYCSSTRUCT * mycsstruct) as you do. I am not sure if it should cause any problem as I am not a PInvoke expert, but keep it in mind just in case. One last thing you might need to tweak is the size of bool (if it's 1 byte as I expect, you should use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]. It's demonstrated in the SO post mentioned above.
